# Deserializing JSON with json.net

Tags: json.net

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON text into a C# class using JSON.Net.

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": [{
    "groupid": "5",
    "name": "Discovered hosts",
    "internal": "1",
    "flags": "0"
}, {
    "groupid": "7",
    "name": "Hypervisors",
    "internal": "0",
    "flags": "0"
}, {
    "groupid": "2",
    "name": "Linux servers",
    "internal": "0",
    "flags": "0"
}, {
    "groupid": "8",
    "name": "Network Gear",
    "internal": "0",
    "flags": "0"
}, {
    "groupid": "1",
    "name": "Templates",
    "internal": "0",
    "flags": "0"
}, {
    "groupid": "6",
    "name": "Virtual machines",
    "internal": "0",
    "flags": "0"
}, {
    "groupid": "4",
    "name": "Zabbix servers",
    "internal": "0",
    "flags": "0"
}],
"id": 2
```

}

The classes are as follows:

```
    public class getHostsResponse
    {
        public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
        public List<getHostsRecord> hostlist { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class getHostsRecord
    {
        public string groupid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string internala { get; set; }
        public string flags { get; set; }
    }
```

The deserialize statement is:

```
getHostsResponse response2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getHostsResponse>(response);
```

The jsonrpc and id fields deserialize correctly, but the hostlist field is null.

Do I have the classes (specifically the gethostrecords) set up incorrectly to receive the deserialized stream?

Thanks.

Bryan Hunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the property names in your classes need to match the JSON (or else you need to use [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) attributes on each property to indicate the JSON name where they differ).

Change the name of the `hostlist` property in your `getHostsResponse` class to `result` and it should start working.  You've also misspelled the `internal` property in the `getHostsRecord` as `internala`.

Revised classes are as follows:

```
public class getHostsResponse
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public List<getHostsRecord> result { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class getHostsRecord
{
    public string groupid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string internal { get; set; }
    public string flags { get; set; }
}
```

Or, using the `[JsonProperty]` approach:

```
public class getHostsResponse
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public List<getHostsRecord> hostlist { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class getHostsRecord
{
    public string groupid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string internal { get; set; }
    public string flags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Argh.  That was it.  I matched up for all of the element names, didn't realize that I needed to do that for the array name too.  Thanks for pointing that out Brian.

Comment: No worries; glad I could help.